# How to change the color of a cell of Datagridview by comparing the cell date with today's Date in C#.net?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to C#,this is my first project on C# language and my backend is Mysql, I am stuck at a particular point ,I am having a form which is containing a datagridview which is binded with database value,in that i have a column "TNS_Date"  It is The Expiration Date of Product ,I want that if the TNS_Date is Greater then the Current Date so the Background Colour of that particular Cell Should Get Red in colured ,How could i do this ,please help me with this

I am using winforms and till now i had tried this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TNSFormdgv.Rows)
{
    var now                =  DateTime.Now;
    var expirationDate     =  DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[15].Value.ToString());
    var OneMonthBefore     = expirationDate.AddDays(-30);
    if (now > OneMonthBefore && now < expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (now > expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

when i am executing the Project i am getting this Error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This is  my whole code for that particular form please check it where i am getting wrong

```
public partial class TNS_Subscription : Form
{
    public TNS_Subscription()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TNSSubscriptionForm();
    }
    private void TNSFormBackbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    public void TNSSubscriptionForm()
    {
        string ConString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=ajay";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("Select acmecmpdetails.Cmp_Number,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_Name,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_AdminId,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_Address1,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_Country1,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_State1,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_City1,acmecmpdetails.Cmp_PostalCode,acmecmpdetails.Contact_Person1,acmecmpdetails.LandLine_Number1,acmecmpdetails.MobileNumber,acmecmpdetails.Cntct_Emailid,acmetally_detail.TallySerial_No,acmetally_detail.Tally_Release,acmetally_detail.Tally_Edition,acmetally_detail.TNS_Date,acmetally_detail.Tally_PrefPartner,acmetally_detail.Tally_accountId from acmesolutionsdatabase.acmecmpdetails INNER JOIN acmesolutionsdatabase.acmetally_detail ON acmesolutionsdatabase.acmecmpdetails.TallySerial_No= acmesolutionsdatabase.acmetally_detail.TallySerial_No;", conDataBase);


        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter cddsda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            cddsda.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            cddsda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            TNSFormdgv.DataSource = bsource;
            cddsda.Update(dbdataset);
            for(int i=0;i<TNSFormdgv.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(TNSFormdgv.Rows[i].Cells["TNS_Date"].Value.ToString()) > System.DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                     TNSFormdgv.Rows[i].Cells["TNS_Date"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

            }
        }    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: is it asp.net or winforms/wpf? What did you try? What the point of adding mysql tag?

Comment: @Uriil OP mentioned DataGridView. So I guess it has to be Windows Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<MyGridView.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(MyGridView.Rows[i].Cells["TNS_Date"].Value.ToString()) > System.DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        MyGridView.Rows[i].Cells["TNS_Date"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

It will change the backcolor of the cell "TNS_Date" if its value is greater than current date.

**OR**
You can use the index of the column `TNS_Date` like:

If the index of the column `TNS_Date` is 3, then:

```
for(int i=0;i<MyGridView.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(MyGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()) > System.DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        MyGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I hope it would solve the problem.

Comment: I am still getting the error 

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"          Because of which the loop is not getting executed

Comment: When i press the button to open the form containing the datagridview that time i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Make sure the `InitializeComponent()` is called in the form constructor. And replace `MyGridView` with your gridview name.

Comment: Make sure that you have some data in `TNSFormdgv` before executing this code.

Comment: I have data in TNSFormdgv sir

Comment: Then the reason for the error must be something else, not with this code part. Check your program well.

Comment: when i am adding the code in the program file then only i am getting the error other than i am not getting the error ,i had edited my question with the whole code you can check that is i had done some mistake

Comment: Make sure the column name is exacley "TNS_Date" or use the index of the cell (See edited answer).

Comment: Sir,when i am providing the index number or the column names so i am getting the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" as index number start with 0 so if you will see my query so the TNS_Date fall upon 16 it means the index number is '15' so i am getting the error if either i am increasing or decreaing the index number so i am getting "The string was not recongnized as a valid DateTime. There is unknown word starting at  index  0."

Comment: I had done these Couple of week ago ,just i were using the default event of Datagridview that's why i were not getting the color in gridview data  ,i had changed the event to desired event and it work , Thank you Sir

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample that could help:

```
  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged;

        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

        list.Add(new MyClass { ID = 1, Name = "1", Date = DateTime.Now });
        list.Add(new MyClass { ID = 2, Name = "2", Date = DateTime.Now });
        list.Add(new MyClass { ID = 3, Name = "3", Date = DateTime.Now });
        list.Add(new MyClass { ID = 4, Name = "4", Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

    }

    void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop through all the cells where date is in future
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.Cells[2].Value != null) && (DateTime)row.Cells[2].Value > DateTime.Now)
            {
                row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it's in Windows Forms as you are using datagridview.

For datagridview you'd be required to iterate through each cell of the grid to find the right cell and set the background colour.

I've created following code to do so.

```
void loadGrid()
{
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        dtData.Columns.Add("TNS_Date");

        DataRow dRow;

        clmDate.DataPropertyName = "TNS_Date";
        dRow= dtData.NewRow();

        dRow["TNS_Date"] = "20-01-2014";
        dtData.Rows.Add(dRow);

        dRow = dtData.NewRow();

        dRow["TNS_Date"] = "20-02-2014";
        dtData.Rows.Add(dRow);


        dRow = dtData.NewRow();

        dRow["TNS_Date"] = "20-03-2014";
        dtData.Rows.Add(dRow);

        dgvGrid.DataSource = dtData;


        for (int i = 0; i <= dgvGrid.RowCount - 1; ++i)
        {
            //Finding the right cell to change colour.
            if(DateTime.Parse(dgvGrid["TNS_Date", i].Value.ToString()) >= DateTime.Now.Date)
            dgvGrid[0, i].Style.BackColor = Color.Bisque;

        }
```

}

Comment: But Sir where we had declared the local variable clmDate

Comment: clmDate is the column name in datagridview. If you are binding the datatable with datagridview then it will be the desired column name  in your datatable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using asp.net datagridview then use a template field to do that. You can find more details about template field here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

Comment: DataGridView is control in Windows form. For web, there is GridView.